# How can I make my Macbook Pro's headphone jack stop "humming"?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, music, headphones

Switched recently from a Lenovo PC and one thing on my mac bothered me. Headphones plugged into my Macbook pro 13" (latest version) "hum" with static when there is no audio playing. Then after a short period of time, they stop humming, as if all power to the port is turned off. When any sound plays, it starts again. Anybody know of any setting in the Mac "bios" (or whatever they call it) or with drivers or software to get it to stop humming? It's rather annoying.

Comment: This "hum" you speak of happens on my iPad and I've just gotten used to it. It's not noticeable when sounds are playing.

Comment: Does the humming change or stop when you unplug everything else, including the magsafe power cable? Does it change when you play with the screen brightness? Does it change when the Mac is first turned on and still cold to the touch?

Comment: I've only noticed noise using apple ear buds, if I use any other set of headphones I don't hear humming of any sort.

Comment: I can confirm that removing the MagSafe cable solves the problem. Still, I'm looking for a permanent solution that would allow me to power the mac :)

Comment: 10 years later I see myself with new MacBook and the same problem but unplugging the magsafe 3 power cable does to fix the issue.

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution to my problem. For some reason (who knows why) the headphone output was set to 16-bit. Of course that's going to sound awful.

To fix this, head to 'Audio MIDI Setup' (can be found with Spotlight) and change the 'Built-in Output' to 32-bits.

Comment: Audio MIDI Setup can be found in the Utilities (Command-Shift-U, from the Finder, or Utilities folder inside the Applications folder). Thanks: this did solve my (light) humming problem.

Comment: I did not know this. I've noticed the odd bit of poor quality from the headphone jack, was set to 20bit. I wonder if setting it to 32.48K will help. Thank you!

Comment: Is this the mac default? Just changed it to 32 and the difference is very noticeable.

Comment: This answer really makes no sense at all. "CD Audio" is 16-bit & in the 40 years it's been popular has never been known to 'hum'.

Comment: Subtract nearly a decade from that, this answer was from 2013! I don't know what caused it at the time, but changing this setting fixed my problem. Resampling? Antialiasing? SNR around the low numbers? A bug in Mac OS X circa 2013? Who knows.

Comment: There have been instances over the years when the clock sync on DACs have had 'the jitters'. The way to actually test this is to change the frequency then change it back again. The act of changing it resets the clock. Changing it back then 'proves' it wasn't actually the frequency itself at fault, causing the 'hum' [It shouldn't actually be hum, it should be a 'fuzziness' in the signal, depending on how badly the clock was mis-firing. Sometimes it would even result in silence until its elbow was jogged to wake it up.]

Answer (score 12):

My macbook air also hums into my Bose earbuds. Disconnecting the magsafe power cable lessens it, but not by much. Touching the body of the computer dramatically decreases the hum (the more skin that touches, the greater the decrease).

Comment: I experienced the exact same issue. Unplugging the monitor and power cord just caused different hums. Using the 3 prong power cord is what cleared it up.

Answer (score 8):

What you are hearing is the intrinsic noise of the Macbook's [DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) and [output buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier).

The output does actually power down when it goes unused for a certain period of time, which is why the noise goes away. The analog output is powered down to save battery.

Unfortunately, since the noise is intrinsic to the system, the only way to disable it is to completely disable the ability to output any sound.

There may be a way to modify the period of time it takes before the output gets powered down, but I am not familiar with any.

Comment: … or you could try using an external (e.g. USB-powered) DAC that has a lower noise, but thats quite a lot trial & error.

Comment: "Step 1:Plug it in, Step 2:Install Drivers".... That's a lot of trial and error?

Answer (score 5):

Closing my web browser solved my buzz problem!

My Mac Pro started an electronic type of buzzing sound suddenly in the past few weeks.

The sound was coming from the audio output (headphone jack or firewire audio output - same issue)

I had incorporated some new speakers recently and I thought maybe it was some kind of new grounding problem. While attempting to pursue a solution to the problem, on a whim I decided to shut down my mac to see if that might do anything.

While preparing to shut down I was closing various programs. Then I closed down Google Chrome, on which I had about 10-15 tabs open... and the sound went away!

I've never experienced something like this before.  I'm imagining perhaps it was some kind of issue with one of the pages I had up.

I've often had multiple browsers windows, each with multiple tabs open and never had this kind of thing happen... so this was unique experience for me.

Comment: Had the same problem, closed everything and the sound card went back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

The hum is also present for me, even with unplugging everything. Actually, if you have a look (or at least, for me, this is the case) if you touch the body of the machine, it ceases to hum. It must be some kind of static buildup of charge on the aluminium body, and when you touch it, your body acts as a very large condenser.

When you can ground the machine with your body, you might want to check the power cord and replace an ungrounded "duck head" or cord with one that goes to a properly grounded wall receptacle. Also, take a toothbrush to the magsafe connectors to ensure all the springs work and make contact to the connector on the mac.

If you use an external USB I/O (I use a mixer, for I'm a session musician), the hum is not plagueing the alternative sound source.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the above may apply, but this solved mine;

As soon as I unplugged from power, the buzz went. Nothing to doo with ground loops, or bad connectors ( even though 3.5 mm plugs differ surprisingly ).

The answer was that the laptop Battery was long overdue for replacement. When power is put through this for charging, you get the hum. I have about 40min of battery life without main charging. so it is enough to drive some midi gear from a sound font sampler for a few songs, then mute the channel while I feed it mains power again during the break.

I double checked the exact setup by plugging to a refurbished MacBook Air and confirmed it. ( actually the wife suggested this solution, you know what they say, don't argue with a woman, she's always right :)

Answer (score 0):

Bmike above said that when he touched his, it got rid of the problem. if it's true for you as well OP, try touching the base and a brick wall or something, or lick your fingers and wipe the bottom with them a little. for any other solutions look up how to get rid of static electricity on google.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution: plug in three pronged charger instead of two pronged charger**

Other answers have mentioned this but with other cruft in the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for those who are using the MagSafe adapter without the ground. The MagSafe you can connect to the power wall socket in two ways:

1. Using the 1.5-meter cable which has grounding pins.
2. Using the adapter that has only 2 pins and no grounding that's causing the noise.

Buy a cable with grounding and the noise will disappear.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Answer (score -1):

iMac 27 inch - late 2012, i7

Well, Apple probably won't like this advice but it EASILY worked for me :

- I use the headphone jack output for audio playback from my iMac (Pro Tools, iTunes, etc) and after upgrading to the iMac from my Mac Pro (early 2008, quad core) physically configured the same way (headphone jack output to my speakers) the iMac would constantly emit a BUZZ shortly after any sound was outputted from it.  i.e. : something like a system sound would play, there would be silence, and then after about 10 seconds or so the BUZZ would constantly output.
- read and tried a few things that were completely useless and weird to even give a try (but I did regardless) - things like : 'zap the PRAM' ... reset the SMC ... switch to 32bit .... all weird, misguided and did not solve the problem.
- I shut down the iMac, unplugged the power cable from the wall, grabbed a pair of needle nose pliers and then ripped off the GROUND PLUG from the power cable.  Plugged it back in, booted back up and SOLVED.  Apple's mention of a "ground loop" possibly being the problem in other posts was the best advice I found.  They did/would not offer this solution but for me, after working in recording studios for more than 25 years now and experiencing MANY types of grounding issues with regard to BUZZ in the audio signal - it led me to just rip that ground plug off and move forward.
- As a professional I cannot profess to know that the possible negative implications might be from having a non-grounded iMac but let me just say that this is not the first time that I have done this with a computer or any type of gear for that matter to just basically "move on".

Let's see if Apple allows this post.  Believe me - try it!  If it doesn't help then make sure that you have a replacement IEC power cable (the one that has a female 3-pronged end and a male 3-pronged end) to swap out to if not successful.

Comment: Apple doesn't have anything to do with this site and they don't control any of the content.

Comment: This is bad advice.  While I understand it solved your problem with the hum, it doesn't resolve the real issue which is that there is a problem with the electrical wiring in your outlets/breaker.  The ground prong is there for safety purposes...ie if there is a hardware malfunction the ground gives a place for the voltage to dissipate so you don't get a shock.  Of course if the grounding in your house is broken...then it doesn't help you anyway.  Better to fix the wiring in your house than remove a safety feature.

Answer (score -1):

This post is now the highest ranked answer when you Google

> macbook headphone buzzing

, so I thought I´d leave my answer to this question as well.

As others have mentioned above, I also had the issue where I heard a low frequent buzzing/humming sound when I had my headphones (Bose QuietComfort) connected to my Macbook. If I touched the Macbook chassis with my hand, the sound faded. If I lifted my hand, the sound was more present.

There appears to be multiple ways to resolve this issue, depending on the root cause!

In my experience, adjusting the output in "Audio Midi Setup" did nothing. Instead, I discovered the audio jack connected to my headphone (and not my Macbook) was not fully inserted. When I pushed the connector back into the headphones, the buzz was gone!