# Macbook's speakers "pop" when entering stand-by mode

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, speakers, pop

On my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017) I have noticed a problem with popping sound. It happens both on running on AC adapter and battery: Macbook makes light pop sound (like from static electricity) from left or right speaker (this is random) after stopping playback of any audio –  when speakers enter stand-by mode (turn off).

Here is a video with that sound: https://youtu.be/H2gxz53QTZ4 (+ comments) and
here is some discussion on this topic:

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/378356/Strange+pop+sound+sometimes
https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookpro/comments/714kae/does_your_macbook_pro_2017_pop_after_audio/

I tried SMC and NVRAM reset, I also reinstalled MacOS (to High Sierra, now I'm back on Mojave) but with no help.

When I have headphones connected to Macbook, then in exactly same time (entering stand-by after audio playback) I can also hear some unexpected sound – like disconnecting headphones from power.

Do you have same experience with your Macbook?
Is there any possibility to modify stand-by setting?

Somebody tried to work around this by writing antipop script: https://www.tomsick.net/projects/antipop.html
But I don't want to disable stand-by completely, so this program is useless for me.

Comment: This is usually due to a bad capacitor in the audio circuitry.  The logic board will need to be exchanged or if you can find a company that specializes in logic board repair, it’s just something you’ll have to live with.  An alternate solution would be to get a [USB DAC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/247246/119271).

Comment: I see. But I'm not sure this will be the case. Before coronavirus I was in Apple Store and I checked brand new Macbook and it also made pop sound after playback. It must be said that is very silent pop. For example in that Store I had to ask staff for stop playing music in whole Store to hear that pop...

Comment: This is an “audio” thing.  I had a vintage Marantz stereo that started to buzz, hiss, and pop.  I was interested  in and had a basic understanding of electronic circuitry and luckily the elderly tech spent hours explaining why bad and even cheap components can create those noises and it comes down to not have  “clean” voltage.

Comment: One of the problems I have with Apple is that they will charge an uber premium for their products, but put in, not even “good” but clearly mediocre components to save on cost. They have a major “last mile” problem that they have **luckily** been able to avoid because there are more “fans” than users. I’ve held off on upgrading my laptop until now because of keyboard and display issues. The bottom line is that you are hearing those pops because there’s a build quality issue.