# Can't switch my sound output on my Bose headset from 16-bits to 32-bits

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a buzzing/humming sound when I play sounds on my MacBook Pro. I read that you need to change the sound output from 16- to 32-bits, but when I change it, it doesn't work. When I change it to 32-bits, it just turns right back to 16-bits. How do I switch to 32-bits?

Comment: Where did you read this (link) and how did you attempt change from 16 to 32 bit? Do you have the problem only with the headset or with any audio device? Does the headset work on other devices without buzzing?

Comment: I read it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8039/how-can-i-make-my-macbook-pros-headphone-jack-stop-humming. The top comment. I only have the problem with this headset, but it's also the only bluetooth headset I use, so I don't know if it's the same with other bluetooth headphones. The headset works completely normal when I use it on my iPhone

Comment: Changing the output frequency should have absolutely zero effect on any amount of 'hum'. The top-voted answer on your link makes no sense whatsoever as a solution to the issue.